# URL routing in Django

Tags: django, url

I am prrety new in URLs and Django and got some questions.

For now I have 2 HTML templates which are routing correctly: home.html and ladder.html .

What do I have to do to go from my ladder.html(ladder/) back to my home.html("") if I click to home again nothing is happening.
And as second when I am on ladder and click ladder again it adds another ladder/ to the URL and Im getting a router error , how can I resolve this ?

Thanks for the help.

I will show the code of my navbar wher my href attributes are so u can understand what I mean and my urls.py

My hrefs:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="ladder/">Ladders</a>
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages.views import home_view,ladder_view
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ladder/',ladder_view),

]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path for home is `/`, so you can write this as:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

But that being said ***hardcoding* URLs is not a good idea**. You should give your URLs a name, and use the [**`{% url ... %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag, like:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages.views import home_view,ladder_view
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ladder/',ladder_view, name='ladder'),
]
```

In the template you can then write this as:

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'ladder' %}">Ladders</a>
</li>
```

If you later for example change the `path`, or move that view to another app, then the URLs will change, since Django "calculates" the URLs when rendering the template. The Django documentation has a topic named [*Naming url patterns* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) on that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the tag to call any route . for this you must :

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'ladder' %}">Ladders</a>
</li>
```

in this step. when you set name to route you can call it with :

```
{% url 'home' %}
```